# Basic Tic Tac Toe Game: Somehow, when I call a function in a different file, that function changes a list in the original file

Tags: python, python-3.x

main.py:

```
import ai
import utility


def main(): # {
    # Main Loop Variables
    win_condition = '*'
    player_turn = True
    turn = 0
    board_state = [['*', '*', '*'],
                   ['*', '*', '*'],
                   ['*', '*', '*']]
    # Start of Main Turn Loop
    while (win_condition == '*') and (turn <= 9):
        turn += 1
        print('Turn: ', turn)
        player_input = 0

        for y in range(3):  # Prints Board
            print(board_state[y][0] + board_state[y][1] + board_state[y][2])

        if player_turn:  # Player Moves
            player_turn = not player_turn

            player_input = int(input("Enter 1, 2, 3...9")) - 1

            board_state[int(player_input) // 3][int(player_input) % 3] = 'X'
        else:  # Computer moves
            print('Thinking...')
            player_turn = not player_turn

            ai_move = ai.random(board_state)

            print(utility.list_possible_states(board_state))
            print(board_state)

            board_state[int(ai_move) // 3][int(ai_move) % 3] = 'O'

        win_condition = utility.test_for_win(board_state)

# }    
main()
```

ai.py:

```
import utility
from random import randrange


def random(board_state):
    possible_moves = utility.list_possible_moves(board_state)

    return possible_moves[randrange(len(possible_moves))]
```

utility.py:

```
def test_for_win(test_board):  # {
    return_value = '*'
    for y in range(3):  # Tests for horizontal win.
        test_set = set(test_board[y])
        if len(test_set) == 1 and not ('*' in test_set):
            print("The winner is " + test_board[y][1])
            return_value = test_board[y][1]
            break

    for x in range(3):  # Tests for vertical win.
        test_list = []
        for y in range(3):
            test_list.append(test_board[y][x])
        test_set = set(test_list)
        if (len(test_set) == 1) and not ('*' in test_set):
            print("The winner is " + test_board[1][x])
            return_value = test_board[1][x]
            break

    test_list = []
    for xy in range(3):  # Tests for diagnoal win (-)
        test_list.append(test_board[xy][xy])
    # print(test_list, len(test_list))              #Debugging
    if (len(set(test_list)) == 1) and not ('*' in test_list):
        print("The winner is " + test_board[1][1])
        return_value = test_board[1][1]

    test_list = []
    for xy in range(3):  # Tests for diagnoal win (+)
        test_list.append(test_board[xy][2 - xy])
    # print(test_list, len(test_list))              #Debugging
    if (len(set(test_list)) == 1) and not ('*' in test_list):
        print("The winner is " + test_board[1][1])
        return_value = test_board[1][1]

    return return_value
# }


def list_possible_moves(board):  # {
    possible_moves = []
    for move_counter in range(9):  # Prints Possible Moves to List
        if board[move_counter // 3][move_counter % 3] == '*':
            possible_moves.append(move_counter)

    return possible_moves
# }


def list_possible_states(board):  # {
    possible_moves = list_possible_moves(board)

    xoro = '*'
    if (len(possible_moves)) % 2 == 0:
        xoro = 'O'
    else:
        xoro = 'X'

    possible_states = []
    for move in possible_moves:
        board_s = board
        board_s[move // 3][move % 3] = xoro
        possible_states.append(board_s)
        del board_s

    return possible_states
# }
```

If I comment out this print statement in main.py:

```
print(utility.list_possible_states(board_state))
```

This prints out:

```
[['X', '*', '*'], ['*', '*', '*'], ['*', '*', '*']]
```

But if I don't comment out that line it prints out:

```
[['X', 'O', 'O'], ['O', 'O', 'O'], ['O', 'O', 'O']]
```

How is the variable board_state being changed in the function main() from the function list_possible_states()? And if you have any suggestions / see any major errors don't hesitate to bring them up as well.

*edit to utility.py{

```
import copy

def test_for_win(test_board):  # {
    return_value = '*'
    for y in range(3):  # Tests for horizontal win.
        test_set = set(test_board[y])
        if len(test_set) == 1 and not ('*' in test_set):
            print("The winner is " + test_board[y][1])
            return_value = test_board[y][1]
            break

    for x in range(3):  # Tests for vertical win.
        test_list = []
        for y in range(3):
            test_list.append(test_board[y][x])
        test_set = set(test_list)
        if (len(test_set) == 1) and not ('*' in test_set):
            print("The winner is " + test_board[1][x])
            return_value = test_board[1][x]
            break

    test_list = []
    for xy in range(3):  # Tests for diagnoal win (-)
        test_list.append(test_board[xy][xy])
    # print(test_list, len(test_list))              #Debugging
    if (len(set(test_list)) == 1) and not ('*' in test_list):
        print("The winner is " + test_board[1][1])
        return_value = test_board[1][1]

    test_list = []
    for xy in range(3):  # Tests for diagnoal win (+)
        test_list.append(test_board[xy][2 - xy])
    # print(test_list, len(test_list))              #Debugging
    if (len(set(test_list)) == 1) and not ('*' in test_list):
        print("The winner is " + test_board[1][1])
        return_value = test_board[1][1]

    return return_value
# }


def list_possible_moves(board):  # {
    testtest = copy.copy(board)
    possible_moves = []
    for move_counter in range(9):  # Prints Possible Moves to List
        if testtest[move_counter // 3][move_counter % 3] == '*':
            possible_moves.append(move_counter)

    return possible_moves
# }


def list_possible_states(board):  # {
    test = copy.copy(board)
    possible_moves = list_possible_moves(test)

    xoro = '*'
    if (len(possible_moves)) % 2 == 0:
        xoro = 'O'
    else:
        xoro = 'X'

    possible_states = []
    for move in possible_moves:
        board_s = test
        board_s[move // 3][move % 3] = xoro
        possible_states.append(board_s)
        del board_s

    return possible_states
# }
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your `list_possible_states` function is that the line `board_s = board` doesn't do what you seem to expect it to do. It doesn't copy the `board` list. It just creates a new reference to the existing list object. When you change the list's contents, you'll see the change through both references.

The fact that `list_possible_states` is defined in a different module than where you call it from doesn't matter, since it's not modifying a global variable. You're passing it a reference to the `board`, and it's modifying it by mistake.

If you want to make a copy, use the `deepcopy` function from the `copy` module in the standard library:

```
board_s = copy.deep_copy(board)
```

Just using `copy.copy` (as you're doing in your update) is not enough, since `board` is a nested list and you need new lists at all levels.

Comment: Done, Done and Done, Thank you very much.

Comment: Why does it create a reference though? What is a reference? And how do references work through functions?

Comment: All variables in Python are references to objects. They're like pointers in C and C++. Indeed, Python objects in CPython (the normal Python interpreter) are implemented as pointers! Other than variables, there can be other kinds of references, like a dictionary having references to its keys and values. When you pass an object as an argument to a function, the function gets a reference to the object (which then works like a local variable).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but it could be because in the for loop:

```
for move in possible_moves:
    board_s = board
    board_s[move // 3][move % 3] = xoro
    possible_states.append(board_s)
    del board_s
```

board_s might be being pointed to board, rather than being set to a copy of what board is. This would explain the list values changing. If this is true, when board_s is deleted at the end of the loop, the pointer is being deleted, not the board itself.

```
board_state = [['*', '*', '*'],['*', '*', '*'],['*', '*', '*']]
board_s = board_state
board_s[0][0] = 'O'
print board_state
```

Same result ^

Comment: I thought something like this might be happening, but for the sake of the earth I couldn't figure out why nor how. Any ideas?

Comment: In terms of it being in a different file, I think that as soon as it is imported, it is treated as if it is within this file.

Comment: So it seems that within list_possible_states you would want to create a whole new array and populate it with the values in the original board.

Comment: That is exactly right. I want to create a new list with all possible board states in it. Basically, I want to show what each possible move would look like on a board if played.

Comment: But somehow, this function list_possible_states is changing the actual state of the board in the main function, it doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Looks like that'd need to be done via another loop then. Or, you could refactor what the board_state is from an array to a class. Then, you could instantiate a new board_state object with the same values as the current board state. Check this out, it allows you to create copies of objects without having to write it.

http://effbot.org/pyfaq/how-do-i-copy-an-object-in-python.htm

Comment: Well since it's being passed by reference, it technically gets linked from main to the external function.

Comment: "Check this out" -I think you might have meant to post a link, but I can't see anything?

Comment: Haha yeah, forgot it at first.

Comment: Here's what I tried, didn't work, is this what you meant?

Comment: Not sure what you're referring to. It can definitely be done with another for loop in list_possible_states.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm a little new to this. Could you explain just a wee bit more how I could do it with another for loop?

Comment: I'll post it in another answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
def list_possible_states(board):
possible_moves = list_possible_moves(board)

xoro = '*'
if (len(possible_moves)) % 2 == 0:
    xoro = 'O'
else:
    xoro = 'X'

possible_states = []

...START OF NEW...

board_s = []

for i in range(0, len(board)):
    for j in range(0, len(board[i])):
        board_s[i][j] = board[i][j]

for move in possible_moves:
    board_s[move // 3][move % 3] = xoro
    possible_states.append(board_s)
    del board_s

...END OF NEW....

return possible_states
```